# Error message "there are no writable config files" when try to open "Manage nuget packages"

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Preview shows error message **"there are no writable config files"** when try to open "Manage nuget packages" on "References"

[image]

[image]

C# solution can be found: https://github.com/constructor-igor/TechSugar/trunk/Powershell/Sample_Read_Process_Write/CustomerObjects

Answer (score 8):

Had same issue, it is not related to the solution/project, simply delete NuGet configuration file and it should work again.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
```

Comment: I ran in to a similar issue that was also fixed by removing the `NuGet.config` file (which, as it turned out, was just chock full of `NUL`s).

In my case Visual Studio was crashing every time I went to the _Package sources_ option under _NuGet Package Manager_ in the options dialog.